# No muestra por consola la salida en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, consola

Tengo un problema en Eclipse y es que no me muestra por consola a partir del segundo System.out.println, estoy utilizando Eclipse 3.7.1 y Java 1.8.0_45 que es lo que me mandan, y también tengo que utilizar la siguiente clase de un lector por teclado, para poner una cadena en mayúsculas, minúsculas etc...:

Lector:

```
package edu.metor.actividad1;

/*
 * @(#)Lector.java  1.1 27-Nov-2004
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2004 José M. Ordax. All rights reserved.
 * 
 * This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the MIT License
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * La clase <code>Lector</code> sirve para leer datos de distintos
 * tipos por el teclado. Posee un método estático para leer cada tipo.
 * <p><p/>
 * Un ejemplo de su uso sería:
 * <blockquote><pre>
 *     System.out.println("Introduzca un String: ");
 *     String unString = Lector.leerString();
 *     System.out.println("El String introducido es: " + unString);
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * <p>
 *  Al realizar operaciones de entrada/salida o conversiones entre tipos
 *  se pueden producir problemas (excepciones en la tecnología Java) como
 *  por ejemplo {@link java.lang.NumberFormatException} o
 *  {@link java.io.IOException}.
 *  Todos estos problemas están controlados y gestionados por la clase 
 *  <code>Lector</code> y en caso de producirse, se mostrará un mensaje
 *  de error por pantalla explicando el motivo.
 *
 * @author  José M. Ordax
 * @version 1.1, 27-Nov-2004
 * @see     java.lang.System#in
 * @see     java.io.InputStream
 * @see     java.io.InputStreamReader
 * @see     java.io.BufferedReader
 * @see     java.io.IOException
 */
public class Lector 
{
    // Atributos.
    private static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Constructor.
    private Lector()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Lee un byte por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el byte introducido o 0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static byte leerByte()
    {
        byte tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un byte.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un short por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el short introducido o 0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static short leerShort()
    {
        short tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Short.parseShort(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un short.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un char por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el primer char introducido o un blanco si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static char leerChar()
    {
        char tmp = ' ';
        try 
        {
            tmp = br.readLine().charAt(0);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un int por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el int introducido o 0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static int leerInt()
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un int.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un long por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el long introducido o 0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static long leerLong()
    {
        long tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un long.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un float por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el float introducido o 0.0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static float leerFloat()
    {
        float tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un float.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un double por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el double introducido o 0.0 si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static double leerDouble()
    {
        double tmp = 0;
        try 
        {
            tmp = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: el dato introducido no se puede convertir en un double.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee una cadena de caracteres por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     el string introducido o <code>null</code> si se produjo algún problema.
     */
    public static String leerString()
    {
        String tmp = null;
        try 
        {
            tmp = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Lee un boolean por teclado. Utiliza la tecla "Enter" para indicar el final del dato.
     *
     * @return     <code>false</code> en cualquier caso a no ser que se introduzca la cadena "true".
     */
    public static boolean leerBoolean()
    {
        boolean tmp = false;
        try 
        {
            tmp = new Boolean(br.readLine()).booleanValue();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema en la operación de entrada de datos.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: hubo un problema no controlado.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```
package edu.metor.actividad1;

public class Actividad1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Introduzca un String: ");
        String electroencefalograma = Lector.leerString();
        System.out.println("El String introducido es: " + electroencefalograma);

        if(electroencefalograma.length() >= 2) {
            System.out.println("Los dos primeros caracteres de la cadena en mayúsculas: " + electroencefalograma.toUpperCase());
        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que crearte una instancia de la clase `Lector` y después usar el método `leerString` para dicha instancia:

```
Lector lector = new Lector();
String electroencefalograma = lector.leerString();
```

Esto lo puedes leer en los [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference.

lo que quiere decir:

> Los métodos de clase no pueden acceder a variables de instancia o a métodos de instancia directamente - deben usar una referencia de objeto.

Comment: Lo intente así y me salia el siguiente error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Lector() is not visible
y la clase Lector me venia con el ejercicio para utilizarla sin cambiar nada...

Comment: @DrWho Tienes que importar la clase Lector en tu programa al principio del todo. Haz un `import Lector;` justo debajo de dónde indicas el package

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer y me da error tambien, que raro... The import Lector cannot be resolved

Comment: @DrWho ¿Tienes a los dos en la misma estructura?¿En la misma carpeta y paquete?

Comment: Si claro, misma carpeta y paquete tambien

Comment: @DrWho Vale, intenta hacer esto: `public class Actividad1 extends Lector{`

Comment: Tambien error Link all references for a local rename (does not change references 
 in other files)

Comment: @DrWho ¿Tienes todavía el import puesto? Si es así, quítalo y deja simplemente lo del extends.

Comment: Me aparece el mismo error con el import y sin el import

Comment: La clase Lector me venia en una carpeta con enlaces, no se si tendrá algo que ver...

Comment: @DrWho ¿A que te refieres con enlaces?

Comment: allclasses-frames, constant-values, deprecated-list, y mas... todos en HTML y carpetas llamadas class-use, index-files, resources

Comment: Te pongo enlace para descargarlo [enlace]http://ge.tt/5WdzV0g2

Comment: @DrWho Vale. ¿Antes te salía el segundo System.out.println? El de "El String introducido es..."

Comment: No, solo me salia el primero, despues de leerString no me aparece

Comment: @DrWho ¿Te daba algún error? Si no, lo que tienes que hacer es introducir un valor en la consola y darle al Enter para que te de el siguiente System.out.println

Comment: Aaaaaaahhhh, añadiendo un String en la consola de Eclipse me lo pone en mayúscula, y yo sin probar eso, al final lo mas sencillo era la solución!!!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Error404 de verdad.

Comment: @DrWho De nada :). Si, al final se me ha ocurrido pensar que igual no había ningún error y que era simplemente el normal funcionamiento del programa. Un placer ayudar. Hay veces que lo más simple resulta ser lo más complicado en lo que darse cuenta. La verdad, me parecía muy raro el supuesto error que te daba. Un saludo! :)